# Android Sdk Not Found

Tags: android, eclipse

I am Beginner at Android Development

I used Eclipse with Android Sdk for some time And i want to shift to android studio

i downloaded android studio from site about 170 mb

[image]

I checked program files there is no android folder

i went to Bin folder and launched studio64 but i can find android sdk or tools
i tried re-downloading android studio but it downloading the same folder
Where can i find sdk folder

Comment: Android Studio does not include the SDK in the download; it says so right on the page. You can use your previous SDK from Eclipse, though. Note that the most recent versions of Android Studio require the SDK to be outside of the Android Studio folder due to the way it verifies updates now.

Answer (score 0):

Go here, https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i

And download the SDK

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download

you can download the version with the android sdk